# Objective-C GameKit Nested Blocks Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks, gamekit

My iPhone game contains the following code:

```
[friendLeaderboardRequest_ loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error)
{
    friendLeaderboardRequest_ = nil;

    if (error)
        return;

    NSMutableArray* playerIDs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (GKScore* score in scores)
        [playerIDs addObject:score.playerID];

    [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:playerIDs withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray* players, NSError* error)
    {
        ...
    }];
}];
```

The nested block call leaks 3 `__NSCFString` objects. Each time, the responsible frame is `-[NSXPCDecoder _initWithRootXPCObject:]`. The nested call causes the leaks. I have moved the call outside of the first block and passed `[NSArray arrayWithObject:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID]` as the array of player IDs and an empty block as the block, and there is no leak. I tried the same dummy call within the first block and the leak occurs again.

Based on these tests, I am assuming that the leak is caused by the Foundation library. Am I missing something? Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: Is there any reference to `self` within the `...` code?

Comment: @sqreept There is a reference to `self` within the `...` code. However, the leak still occurs when I comment out the `...` code.

Comment: You might try wrapping the body of your block in an `@autoreleasepool`. Blocks occurring on separate threads can end up on a separate or missing autorelease pool from what I understand.

Comment: @jlujan Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, it did not prevent the leaks.

Comment: Is this with the static analyser or with Instruments? And is this on the simulator or a device?

Comment: @jrtc27 I found the leaks using instruments with a device.

Comment: Is `friendLeaderboardRequest_` an ivar? If so, then the very first line of your block contains an implicit reference to `self`.

Comment: @KevinBallard Yes, `friendLeaderboardRequest_` is an ivar. I tried commenting out that line and unfortunately, the leaks still occur.

Comment: Same problem, although not with a nested block.  I've added a reply to your post on the Apple developer forums with my thoughts.  I think the bug may be in GK rather than Foundation.